# What does the libkwinnvidiahack4 package do?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kde, kwin

I've just stumbled upon the packages [libkwinnvidiahack4 [image: Install libkwinnvidiahack4]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libkwinnvidiahack4) (and also [libkwinactivenvidiahack4 [image: Install libkwinactivenvidiahack4]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libkwinactivenvidiahack4)). From the description I understand it provides some "hacks" for the KDE window manager in combination with an Nvidia binary graphics driver.

> This package contains a library used by nvidia cards for the KDE window manager.
>
> This package is part of the KDE workspace module.

However, this description lacks what it actually does. I use KDE/Kubuntu and I have the Nvidia graphics driver installed. What are the benefits of installing these packages? What do they do?

I've got the `libkwinnvidiahack4` package installed (probably automatically), but I'm not sure what it is responsible for.

Running through the changelogs (`apt-get changelog libkwinnvidiahack4`) give me the `kde-workspace` changelog with an entry (several snippets taken from it):

> - Move libkwinnvidiahack4 to its own package
> - Add the packages
>
>   - kde-window-manager-active
>   - kde-window-manager-active-gles
>   - libkwinactiveglutils1
>   - libkwinactiveglesutils1
>   - libkwinactiveeffects1abi3
>   - libkwinactivenvidiahack4
> - kde-window-manager/-gles depends on libkwinnvidiahack4
> - Don't install /usr/lib/libkwinnvidiahack.so. No one is supposed to link
>     against libkwinnvidiahack. Make kdebase-workspace-dev depend on
>     libkdecorations4 and libkwineffects1 instead of kde-window-manager now
>     that kde-window-manager contains nothing one can link against.

which also does not explain why these packages are added and what they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a serious bit of Googling I came across [this post](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=89431):

> The only purpose of this file is to be later in the link order than
>   (nvidia's) libGL, thus being initialized by the dynamic linker before
>   it, allowing it to set __GL_YIELD=NOTHING soon enough for libGL to
>   notice it.

Given that the quote is from a certain M-Graesslin, Martin is the chief maintainer in this area, so is a sure-fire source.

Indeed, looking at the source-code

```
apt-get source libkwinnvidiahack4
```

This is actually the kde workspace module.

`kwin/nvidiahack.cpp` is the source module in question - its a small module in itself

Since this *hack* is still in 13.04 - and is part of the core build, yes its still needed and its purpose is to ensure library linking for the OpenGL component of KDE is done in the *correct* functional order.

In terms of what the module does - it looks like it defines a runtime environment variable `__GL_YIELD`

From the [freedesktop spec](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/180.22/README/chapter-11.html)

> OpenGL yield behavior
>
> There are several cases where the NVIDIA OpenGL driver needs to wait
>   for external state to change before continuing. To avoid consuming too
>   much CPU time in these cases, the driver will sometimes yield so the
>   kernel can schedule other processes to run while the driver waits. For
>   example, when waiting for free space in a command buffer, if the free
>   space has not become available after a certain number of iterations,
>   the driver will yield before it continues to loop.
>
> By default, the driver calls sched_yield() to do this. However, this
>   can cause the calling process to be scheduled out for a relatively
>   long period of time if there are other, same-priority processes
>   competing for time on the CPU. One example of this is when an
>   OpenGL-based composite manager is moving and repainting a window and
>   the X server is trying to update the window as it moves, which are
>   both CPU-intensive operations.
>
> You can use the __GL_YIELD environment variable to work around these
>   scheduling problems. This variable allows the user to specify what the
>   driver should do when it wants to yield.

Thus the hack is to never wait and always paint on the OpenGL composite surface - most probably to stop graphical artifacts from appearing.